# What text input component last had the focus?

Tags: java, swing, text, focus

Suppose I have a Java application that has more than one component in which you can enter text.  Now suppose this application also has a dialog that lets you insert a single character (like the dialog in Word that comes up when you select Insert from the Edit menu) into those components.  You want it to insert the character into whichever text component last had the focus.

But how do you know which text component last had the focus?

I could keep track of this manually, by having each text component report to the application whenever it gets the focus and then have the application insert the new character into whichever component that last had the focus.

But this must be a common problem (consider Paste buttons in tool bars---how does it know where to paste it into?).  Is there something already built in to Swing that lets you get a handle to the last text component that had the focus?  Or do I need to write this myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there something already built in to Swing that lets you get a handle to the last text component that had the focus?

You create an Action that extends TextAction. The TextAction class has a method that allows you to obtain the last text component that had focus.

Edit:

You can create your own Action and do whatever you want. The Action can then be added to any JMenuItem or JButton. For example:

```
class SelectAll extends TextAction
{
    public SelectAll()
    {
        super("Select All");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
        component.selectAll();
    }
}
```

If you just want to insert a character at the caret position of the text field then you can probably just do

```
component.replaceSelection(...);
```

Edit 2:

I don't understand what the confusion is with this answer. Here is a simple example:

1. select some text
2. use the mouse to click on the check box
3. tab or use the mouse to click on the "Cut" button

It doesn't matter that the text field doesn't currently have focus when the Action is invoked. The TextAction tracks the last text component that had focus.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextActionTest extends JFrame
{
    JTextField textField = new JTextField("Select Me");
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

    public TextActionTest()
    {
        add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new JCheckBox("Click Me!"));
        add(new JButton(new CutAction()), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TextActionTest frame = new TextActionTest();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
     }

    class CutAction extends TextAction
    {
        public CutAction()
        {
            super("Click to Cut Text");
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
//          JTextComponent component = getTextComponent(e);
            component.cut();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there more details on this documented somewhere?  It looks like DefaultEditorKit.InsertContentAction might be what I need, but the javadoc on it isn't very helpful.

Comment: This is helpful.  But how do you add the Action to a JButton?

Comment: @Paul Reiners - with method `addActionListener( new "concrete listener")`

Comment: That's for adding an ActionListener, not for adding an Action.  You can add an Action to a JMenu, but not a JButton.

Comment: Sure you can use an Action with a JButton. Check out the API. Did you search for anything with "action" in the method name or constructor? Don't forget about the parent classes.

Comment: @dantuch very suboptimal. Instead use setAction(concreteAction). The general rule is to always go with the highest and newest abstraction available.

Comment: @camickr - outch ... my bad (should have actually checked before posting my nonsense answer): you'r right and I was wrong. Thanks for the example! My learn-item of today :-) Will vote this up tomorrow, no more votes (yeah, worked hard today to get a badge)

Comment: @kleopatra, I was thinking your comment was trying to explain the  difference between the two methods. I'm still not sure when you would get a different result.

Comment: @kleopatra, I upvoted him for you ;) anyway - can you provide me some reading with that "general rule"? :)

Comment: @dantuch, Why are you using an ActionListener? You could use a MouseListener and listen for mousePressed/Realeased events. The higher level of abstraction of the ActionListener makes it easier to use. This a a general rule that I'm not sure you will find specifically written anywhere. Its one reason API's evolve over time. Same as KeyEvents. You should not be listening for KeyEvents. You should be using Key Bindings. Read the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Actions" (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more benefits.

Comment: @camickr - simply forget my answer (tried to delete it, but seemingly without success, could you help me to make it disappear?), I was on a wrong track ;-) The only - hypothetical, highly unlikely - context where getTextComponent() != getFocusedComponent is when a focused text component is sending the event with an unfocused textComponent as sender.

Comment: @kleopatra, unfortunately it won't disappear. We have to live with our mistakes :) Don't worry I have many of them. Thats the only situation I could think of as well. I doubt code like that is in the base JDK so I guess it would need to be a custom Action of some kind.

Comment: @camickr [OT] no problem with living with mistakes, have accumulated enough of them (not here, obviously) over the years :-) Just wondering why there is a delete button which doesn't do anything ... hacked by editing.

Answer (score 1):

Just like suggested by @lesmana (+1 for that).
Here you have an example that shows that on focusLost the focus listener returns the previously focused component.

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Focusing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(6);
        tf1.setName("tf1");
        p.add(tf1);
        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(6);
        tf2.setName("tf2");
        p.add(tf2);
        FocusListener fl = new FocusListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("focusGained e.getSource().c=" + ((JComponent) e.getSource()).getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("focusLost e.getSource().c=" + ((JComponent) e.getSource()).getName());
            }
        };
        tf1.addFocusListener(fl);
        tf2.addFocusListener(fl);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(p);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(contentPane);
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

All the best, Boro.

Comment: -1,  The last paragraph basically asks "how does the built in support for a paste function work". This does not answer the question and the answer has already been given. There is no need to attempt to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @camickr I do not see your point being valid, considering the last paragraph "Is there something already built in to Swing that lets you get a handle to the last text component that had the focus?". And my example shows what to do in order to get the text component which had the focus last. Thus it is answering at least a part of the question. Plus I do not see how I am reinventing the wheel? I am just showing a different approach to solve the same problem. In my opinion there is nothing bad in doing so.

Comment: you still miss the point of the question. The question is how does Swing handle "Paste" operations because you don't have to add a FocusListener on every text component to get the default behaviour. The poster wants the same approach for his special processing. Swing was designed to use Actions and text components designed to use TextAction's. You are attempting to recreate the wheel by using a FocusListener intead of the TextAction.

Comment: I downvoted because your answer was given after mine, which indicated you didn't read my answer or understand my answer and you don't understand how Swing works. If you had posted before me I would have just made a comment about a better approach so that hopefully everybody would learn something new.

Comment: @camickr I understand your point. I just wanted to show here a different approach. I disagree with your bold statement about my knowledge, thought. I argue that since you have listeners why not to use them, they are not deprecated or anything around that. I agree that your approach is better let it be even for that it is simply more reusable. I still can see situations, you are completely right not in this user's particular problem, use of listeners would be only options. All the best

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this directly, but you could look into the FocusEvents and the [Focus Subsystem](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

Hopefully there is something in the Focus Subsystem that would fire events that you could listen for.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [`FocusListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) to every text component. The `FocusEvent` object has a reference to the last component which had focus.

Comment: no - you certainly don't want to do that in anything but the most trivial application ;-)