# ActionListener JTextField Java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Suppose we have two JButton objects with captures "Calculate" and "Exit". For the sake of not creating classes implemented by ActionListener, we hve the whole class inplemented by ActionListener, and the method ActionPerformed looks like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Calculate"))
        // do what "calculate" button does
    else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit"))
        System.exit(0);

}
```

My question is what if we have two text fields (JTextField). How should we rewrite actionPerformed method? what is the method to return the JTextField name after the user hits Enter key in that field?

Comment: Write a separate class for your `ActionListener` implementation. When you instantiate it, inject a `JTextField` into the constructor. Then your `actionPerformed` method has access to the text field and can call `getText()` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For the sake of not creating classes implemented by ActionListener...

You should not be using a single listener. Instead you should be using a separate listener for each function you want to implement.

> My question is what if we have two text fields (JTextField).

Instead of adding an ActionListener to the text field you can add a customized `TextAction`. The `TextAction` supports a `getFocusedComponent()` method which will return the text field that currently has focus. This is how all Swing Actions are implement on text components.

For a simple example you can check out: [What text input component last had the focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668690/what-text-input-component-last-had-the-focus/5668974#5668974)