# Is there any way to press ENTER by clicking jButton to pass a event to a jTextfield?

Tags: java, events, keypress, keyevent, enter

I have coded for multi Jtextfields in my project and used KeyPressed Events for each fields for Enter Key. Now I use a Touch Monitor.
And now I want to Use a button and do the same thing by pressing Enter key of the key board.
(Not want grabfocus() or any other solutions. Just want to know is there any way to Press Enter Key by a code and run code each fields I coded.)

Example fields:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L180a.jpg]

Here is an example frame. 
If my cursor is on field 1 I want to run the code I use with `Event.getKeyCode()==10`. 
If my cursor is on field 2 I want to run the code I use with `Event.getKeyCode()==10`. 
If my cursor is on field 3 I want to run the code I use with `Event.getKeyCode()==10`. 
If my cursor is on field 4 I want to run the code I use with `Event.getKeyCode()==10`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can add an `Action` to the Enter button. This Action will need to extend `TextAction`. The TextAction class has a method that will return the last text component that had focus. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668690/what-text-input-component-last-had-the-focus/5668974#5668974 for a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear but perhaps you are looking for an ActionListener to be attached to a button.