# How to know in which JTextPane the cursor is?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtextpane, mouseclick-event

I have several JtextPanes and I want to create a method that set the value of a variable to the name of the TextPane which has been clicked because another methond is going to use it. There's also a button that adds a new jTextPane when the user clicks on it and I want those new TextPanes to inherit that method. Or if you know a simpler way to achieve that I'm open to read you. Let me know if you need more information or more code.

```
static JTextPane focus;

private void redColorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { //Ths is the method that works with the focus variable. It changes the color of the text in the clicked textpane.                                      
        TextEditor.cambiarColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0), focus);
    }
```

Comment: Each JtextPane simply needs a mouse clicked event that changes the focus variable by using something like this inside the event `focus = (JtextPane)e.getSource();`. If you want each JtextPane to have the method, then I suggest extending JtextPane and creating a custom JtextPane that has this function built in.

Comment: *redColorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)* - it seems like you are invoking that method when a button or menu item is clicked. Therefore you should be adding a `TextAction` to the component. The `TextAction` has a `getFocusedComponent` method which will return the last text component that had focus. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668690/what-text-input-component-last-had-the-focus/5668974#5668974 for a basic example.

Comment: *the name of the TextPane which has been clicked* - when you click on a text component the `caret` is painted in the component to indicate you can type into the component. the "cursor" is what is painted when you move the mouse. Using proper terminology will result in better answers.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you want to know the current Swing JTextPane component under the current mouse position? Then try to

- Get current Mouse position

```
Point position = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

- [Get the component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getDeepestComponentAt-java.awt.Component-int-int-) under the mouse location

```
 Component c = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(
     the-root-component,
     position.getX(), 
     position.getY()
 );
 if (c instanceof JTextPane) {
    // do your logic
 }
```